# Como puedo formatear una fecha en JS?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema y es que estoy tratando de formatear una fecha que viene desde una API en este formato: '2024-03-04T00:00:00.000Z', mi problema es que cuando la formateo le resta un día y queda : 03-03-2024. A que se debe? gracias!

```js
      const fechaVisita = '2024-03-04T00:00:00.000Z'
      const fechaUTC = new Date(fechaVisita);

      const options = {
        timeZone: 'America/Santiago',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
      };
      
      const diaFormateado = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(options).format(fechaUTC);
      
      console.log(diaFormateado);
```

Comment: Para complementar la respuesta que te brindó @Mateo: No existe error y está bien que te de un día menos. Cuando sucedió el evento en cuestión en 'America/Santiago' era el día `03-03-2024`  y no el 04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás cometiendo un error al llamar al constructor de [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), pues debes proporcionar el parámetro opcional `locales` si quieres incluir el parámetro `options`.

Además de esto, debes tomar en cuenta que la fecha/hora variará en su representación textual dependiendo de la zona horaria que utilices. Si son las 00:00:00 del día 4 de marzo en el meridiano de Greenwich, dónde se ubica la hora coordinada universal (UTC), son las 21:00:00 en Santiago de Chile, dónde estaré de visita en algunas semanas.

Te dejo algunos ejemplos de representaciones de la misma fecha, en diferentes zonas horarias y formatos.

```js
const fechaVisita = '2024-03-04T00:00:00.000Z'
const fechaUTC = new Date(fechaVisita);

const fechaFormateadaChile = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES', {
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'full',
  timeZone: 'America/Santiago'
}).format(fechaUTC);

const fechaFormateadaUTC = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES', {
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'full',
  timeZone: 'UTC'
}).format(fechaUTC);

const diahoraFormateadoUTC = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",  
  timeZone: 'America/Santiago'
}).format(fechaUTC);

const diaFormateadoUTC = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  timeZone: 'America/Santiago'
}).format(fechaUTC);
      
console.log(fechaFormateadaChile);
console.log(fechaFormateadaUTC);
console.log(diahoraFormateadoUTC);
console.log(diaFormateadoUTC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Interpretemos la fecha que recibes de la API:

```
2024-03-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

Se trata de una fecha en [formato ISO](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). La Z indica que el tiempo se expresa en  UTC.

A esa hora, en UTC-1 todavía son las 23:00 del día 3; en UTC-2 las 22:00 del día 3; en UTC-3 las 21 y así. Por eso parece que se trata de un día antes.

Necesariamente tienes que expresar la hora en un huso horario y convertirla al del usuario.